# Connect "Network is Unreachable" VPS Centos

Tags: networking, centos, vps

I've edited eth0 and I made a mistake where my VPS is now offline and can not even connect to ssh with this message to the Recovery Console:
"Network is unreachable".

What is the command to configure / edit the network!?

[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryC3m.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to your machine. For example via tty then you can edit the network interface. After that you should restart the machine.

See this link to edit the network config.
https://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/administration-linux/configure-centos-6-network-settings/

If you dont have any access to you machine then you have to reset the machine. Some vps hosters have a recovery mode you can try this too.

Comment: I've looked at this article, but what is the command that shows "Device Configuration" through the keyboard?

Comment: You can use nmcli if its installed. It's a simple command line programm that creates the config file.

Comment: As you see in the picture I have no access to the root or server to install something that was so i would be in ssh but it will not let me do anything else except f2 with the display settings i want to know the command as f2 setup for network.

Comment: In recovery mode you have access to the file system of your machine. Use nano or vi to edit the file as described in the link. Then reboot your vps server.

Comment: command how to display nano? According to the Screnshoot you see that the server has its own keystroke